# Sqlite Update Select query -- Referencing table being updated in Order By clause of inner Select

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am trying to update values in a table by the result of a select query. The problem is that I am not allowed to reference the outermost table (the table being updated) in the Order By clause of the innermost table (the table to select the new value).

Suppose I have the following table:

```
MustMatch   PreferredMatch  Old         New       
----------  --------------  ----------  ----------
0           Blue            Old blue              
1           Blue            Wrong matc            
0           Red             Unpreferre            
0           Blue            Preferred
```

I would like to fill in the "New" column for "Old blue". The new value needs to be different from the old value, but match on the MustMatch column. The following query will do this:

```
UPDATE t 
SET New = (
    SELECT innerTable.Old 
    FROM t innerTable 
    WHERE innerTable.Old != t.Old 
        AND innerTable.MustMatch = t.MustMatch 
    LIMIT 1
) WHERE Old = "Old blue";

MustMatch   PreferredMatch  Old         New              
----------  --------------  ----------  -----------------
0           Blue            Old blue    Unpreferred match
1           Blue            Wrong matc                   
0           Red             Unpreferre                   
0           Blue            Preferred
```

Now, I want to add a preference: I want to add `ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch = t.PreferredMatch` to the inner query:

```
UPDATE t 
SET New = (
    SELECT innerTable.Old 
    FROM t innerTable 
    WHERE innerTable.Old != t.Old 
        AND innerTable.MustMatch = t.MustMatch 
    ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch = t.PreferredMatch DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) WHERE Old = "Old blue";
```

This throws an error `Error: no such column: t.PreferredMatch`.

The problem is the reference to `t`. The Order By clause works as intended when I do

```
UPDATE t 
SET New = (
    SELECT innerTable.Old 
    FROM t innerTable 
    WHERE innerTable.Old != t.Old 
        AND innerTable.MustMatch = t.MustMatch 
    ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch = 'Blue' DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) WHERE Old = "Old blue";

MustMatch   PreferredMatch  Old         New            
----------  --------------  ----------  ---------------
0           Blue            Old blue    Preferred match
1           Blue            Wrong matc                 
0           Red             Unpreferre                 
0           Blue            Preferred
```

Why am I not allowed to use table `t` in the Order By clause, even though I can use it in the Where clause? Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: `ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch = 'Blue' DESC` This is incorrect syntax. you cannot write a filter in `ORDER BY` clause. It should be something like this :  `ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch DESC`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. It's not a filter, it's an ordering. I thought ordering by booleans was OK. To rule out, I explicitly mapped the result of the comparison to 0 and 1 with a Case clause: `ORDER BY (CASE WHEN innerTable.PreferredMatch = t.PreferredMatch THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) DESC`
It still doesn't work. Also note that `ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch = 'Blue' DESC` did give the desired result. The error happens because of `t` it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If instead of

```
UPDATE test 
SET New = (
    SELECT innerTable.Old 
    FROM test innerTable 
    WHERE innerTable.Old != test.Old 
        AND innerTable.MustMatch = test.MustMatch 
    ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch = test.PreferredMatch DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) WHERE Old = "Old blue";
```

you use one more level

```
UPDATE test 
SET New = (SELECT newValue FROM
    (SELECT innerTable.Old as newValue,
            innerTable.PreferredMatch = test.PreferredMatch as pick
    FROM test innerTable 
    WHERE innerTable.Old != test.Old 
        AND innerTable.MustMatch = test.MustMatch 
    ORDER BY pick DESC 
    LIMIT 1) foo
) WHERE Old = "Old blue";
```

then it works (you use in order-by a name of the field in select, and in select you can use a field from the external table which is being updated).

IMHO it's a bug in sqlite - there is no reason why a field from an external table could be used in where and select clauses but not in order-by.

Answer (score 0):

I am surprised that your version doesn't work.  Here is a brute force solution:

```
UPDATE t 
    SET New = COALESCE((SELECT it.Old 
                        FROM t it 
                        WHERE it.Old <> t.Old AND
                              it.MustMatch = t.MustMatch AND
                              it.PreferredMatch = t.PreferredMatch
                        LIMIT 1
                       ),
                       (SELECT it.Old 
                        FROM t it 
                        WHERE it.Old <> t.Old AND
                              it.MustMatch = t.MustMatch AND
                              it.PreferredMatch <> t.PreferredMatch
                        LIMIT 1
                       ))
WHERE Old = 'Old blue';
```

Or this might work:

```
UPDATE t 
    SET New = (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN it.PreferredMatch = t.PreferredMatchit.Old 
                                        THEN t.Old
                                   END),
                               MAX(t.Old))
               FROM t it 
               WHERE it.Old <> t.Old AND
                     it.MustMatch = t.MustMatch AND
              );
```

Comment: Thank you. I am surprised as well that it wasn't allowed. Your brute force approach will do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Note that exactly the same run in postgresql simply works:

```
create table test (MustMatch integer,
            PreferredMatch varchar,
            Old varchar,
            New varchar);
-- CREATE TABLE

insert into test (MustMatch, PreferredMatch, Old, New)
values
    (0           ,'Blue'            ,'Old blue'         ,null),
    (1           ,'Blue'            ,'Wrong matc'       ,null),
    (0           ,'Red'             ,'Unpreferre'       ,null),
    (0           ,'Blue'            ,'Preferred'        ,null);
-- INSERT 0 4

UPDATE test 
SET New = (
    SELECT innerTable.Old 
    FROM test innerTable 
    WHERE innerTable.Old != test.Old 
        AND innerTable.MustMatch = test.MustMatch 
    ORDER BY innerTable.PreferredMatch = test.PreferredMatch DESC 
    LIMIT 1
) WHERE Old = 'Old blue';
-- UPDATE 1
```

It really feels like sqlite bug - there should be no difference where you would use an external field in a subselect.